# Using two Raspberry Pi to display an output on the monitor wirelessly

Tags: raspbian, wireless, linux, output

So I have a thesis where I made a podium that has a monitor attached to it with keyboard, router and speakers plus one of my Raspberry Pi.

What I want is to project my first Raspberry Pi, that is connected to the router wirelessly, to show its output on the monitor that's on my podium with my second Raspberry Pi on it. How could I approach this?

Comment: don't expect to be playing back video in a vnc window without massive lag

Answer (score 1):

On your "remote" RPi execute `x11vnc` program. Then from your "local" RPi connect to it with vncviewer: `vncviewer you.remote.pi.ip`. You should see your remote desktop in a window, which you can make fullscreen for better effect.

Comment: By the way, you don't really need to use a Pi as the remote device. VNC can target any computer including generic Linux and OS X, while you can use Remote Desktop Protocol to connect to a remote Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Use a VNC server on your RPi with big display, then connect to it via VNC client from your RPi. It is **that** simple